# Wso2 Api Manager response caching issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created an API and enable the response cache from run time configuration but still gateway sending request to backend API on Version 3.0

Comment: Post details about your exact request.

Comment: This is simple request - https://localhost:8243/signinTest3 which is returning only success statement... when i made response caching enabled from run time configuration my backend server still printing success in the logs

Comment: Need more details about the request. Please run a curl with `-v` and post the output. Do you have any loadbalancer in front of apim?

Comment: there is no load balancer as of now... curl outputHTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,Authorization
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
messageType: text/plain
cacheKey: 12461-123-111117268115-97-69-1974-127-1-187
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2020 16:17:33 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

====signinTest3===

Comment: It seems response caching is working as backend API is not hitting from curl command but i m confused why API is hitting when I am making request from postman...Please clarify

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response cache key includes all the headers and request body, hashed. Therefore, if 2 of your requests have at least one different header, it will be a cache miss.

In the case of Postman, it always sends a random value in `Postman-Token` header. Hense the cache miss always.